# Autocompletion of custom dot access dict in PyCharm

Tags: python, dictionary, pycharm, autocomplete

I have a custom dict class, allowing dot access:

```py
    class dotDict(dict):
        __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
        __setattr__ = dict.__setitem__
        __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__
```

How do I enable autocompletion of dict items in PyCharm? Let's say I have `my_dict.my_item`, I would like PyCharm to suggest `my_item` as soon as I'm done typing `my_dict`.

Answer (score -1):

Adding this method makes it possible:

```py
    def __dir__(self):
        return self.keys()
```

PyCharm 2023.1 and Python 3.10

Comment: I highly doubt that this works and I can't reproduce it, you are seeing something else. For this method to work, Pycharm would have to call `__dir__`, which it can't do in a static context, and for me it doesn't even work when inside of a Python shell.

Comment: @MegaIng all I can say is that it works in my case!